# Render QWidget which is larger than 32767 px

Tags: c++, qt, rendering

I try to render a widget whose size is 3000x50000.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPainter>

class widget: public QWidget{

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override{
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 12, Qt::DashDotLine, Qt::RoundCap));
        painter.drawLine(QPoint(0,0),rect().bottomRight());
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    widget wid;
    wid.setGeometry(0,0,3000,500000);
    QPixmap pixmap(3000,50000);
    wid.render(&pixmap);
    pixmap.save("PATH_TO_IMAGE");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    return a.exec();
}
```

but in output I have this image [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agell.png) after 32767px image was not rendered.
Maybe you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to zoom into your image? I tried to open it in GIMP and GIMP shows me 3000x50000 px image.

Comment: Yes, it creates the image whose size is 3000x50000 but after 32767px I have the black image, but it should be white background with the black line from the top left corner to the bottom right.

Comment: Can I ask why you need such a large widget/image?  What device would benefit from that?  A real use-case would be nice.

Comment: I can see `wid.setGeometry(0,0,3000,500000);` in your code. 500 000 is much more than 50 000. Anyway, even if it was 50 000, such a size does not make any sense, you cannot display it on any monitor. If all you need is to render to pixmap and save it, then I recommend that you paint directly to `QImage`. And if you need to display it on screen, then display only a cropped or zoomed part of the image.

Answer (score 0):

The limitation comes from the internal raster paint engine (see qoutlinemapper_p.h: `const int QT_RASTER_COORD_LIMIT = 32767;`). Upgrade to Qt6 and use a 64bit build - then this limit is updated to 8388607 (2^23-1) pixels.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution which I make is to render the widget to QImage step by step (step should be lower the 32767px) and then copy bits of QImage(using`QImage::bits()`) into one buffer(QVector). And after all these steps you can create one QImage(using QImage(&buffer.first())